# javascript remove where json contains string instead of equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This code currently searches the result array for where the name is "abc" and removes the entire index. How can I make it so it checks for name contains "abc". ie. name could be "abcd" and would still be removed.

```
var i;
for (i = result.length; i--;) {
  if (result[i].name === "abc") { 
    result.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

result is a JSON like
`[{"name": "aaa", "number": "123"},{"name": "abc", "number": "456"},{"name": "abcd", "number": "789"},]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result[i].name.indexOf('abc') === 0
```

Essentially testing that the name starts with abc.

If you want it to just simply be in the name you can do just

```
result[i].name.indexOf('abc') > -1
```

Comment: `"abc".startsWith("a") // true` and `"abc".includes("b") // true`, more elegant than `indexOf`

Comment: `starts with` is a subset of `contains`, but not the whole set of possibilities.

Comment: @JeremyThille as Nope mentioned in the other answer, `includes` is not supported in IE.  https://caniuse.com/#search=include

Comment: This works for me. Can it also be done for where the name does not include "abc"?

Comment: @albinosilver `< 0` or `=== -1` would be the not includes conditional

Answer (score 7):

You can use filter and include to get the result you want

```js
 var array = [{"name": "aaa", "number": "123"},{"name": "abc", "number": "456"},{"name": "abcd", "number": "789"}]
 
 var result = array.filter(item => !item.name.includes("abc"));
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note to OP ► `.includes()` does not work in Internet Explorer. Just in case you are using it.

Comment: To make it IE compatible you'd have to do something like `array.filter(function(item){return item.name.indexOf("abc")});`

Comment: @AndrewBone a small shim is also possible.  https://jsfiddle.net/jhrrpcus/